# How to return a plain ID via GraphQL with API-Platform

Tags: graphql, api-platform.com

Is there a way I can return a 'plain' ID for a particular entity, via GraphQL?

For example:

```
query user ($id: ID!) {
    user (id: $id) {
        id
        plainId
        username
    }
}
```

I have tried adding an additional 'method' on the entity, that has the relevant groups. This DOES add the field to the GraphQL schema, however the value is always NULL.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Need more context, are you using builtin doctrine providers? if so they always return entity IRI, if not you have to hydrate them.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the standard doctrine providers. Is there an appropriate place to extend this functionality? Would it require building out a custom data provider? I was hoping there was a simpler way.